# twitter bootstrap tooltip showed behind modal

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have a tooltip with span inside input-group which is showed in modal popup behind the main modal div..

This is my tooltip inside a form-group

```
<div class="form-group margin-none innerB">
<label for="form_field_name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">label</label>
<div class="col-md-9">      
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="form_field_name" name="form_field_name" class="form-control" value="0" readonly="readonly" />
        <span class="input-group-addon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-placement="top" data-original-title="tooltip text"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Modal Title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="modal_body" class="modal-body padding-none">
                <div class="lead separator center relativeWrap">
                    <p class="innerTB margin-none">
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> loading
                    </p>
                </div>          
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>          
</div>
```

**SOLVED**

I fixed the problem changing this:

```
data-container="body"
```

for:

```
data-container=".modal-body"
```

Answer (score 3):

Modals have higher z-index, check out the z-index of it, and give higher then that of to the tooltip. That might solve it

Answer (score 1):

I use tooltip in a label tag if i change z-index it worked. However, label tag has something and it was gone. Just tooltip is showing. Also, I did not use *data-container="body"*

**UPDATE:**

I add css file *position: fixed;*
now, label and tooltip is showing.

```
.tooltip { 
    z-index: 100000000 !important;
    position: fixed;
}
```

I changed z-index value according to my situation.

Comment: Please post the answer along with code snippet for the question user has asked.